# what are the reasons for these problems in phone gap?

Tags: android, html, css, cordova, cordova-2.0.0

I am using **cordova 2.1.0** for my phonegap application.
I have 2 problems,please help me figure it out.

**Problem 1:**

The on click functionality working on Google nexus device but not on Samsung galaxy S3,device android version 2.2.1 and device android version 2.3.5.

This is how i have implemented it

```
<div id="hi" class="hi"><img src="img/hi.png" onclick="hi()"/></div>

function hi()
{
  window.location.href="hi.html";
}
```

**Problem 2:**

Ontouch and swipe are a very big problem in  emulator android version 2.2.1 and device android version 2.3.5.

I get the following in my log cat,while I touch the input box for typing in the emulator android version 2.3.5.and **the input box vanishes**

```
D/webview(7254): [TouchEvent::Down] [true][false] [-154,208]
D/webview(7254): [WebView::UPDATE_SELECTION] ====== start
```

On swiping,I get the following in my log cat

```
D/webview(7254): [TouchEvent::Down] [true][false] [-115,11]
W/webview(7254): Miss a drag as we are waiting for WebCore's response for touch down.
D/webview(7254): [TouchEvent::Down] [true][false] [9,-31]
D/webview(7254): [WebView::UPDATE_SELECTION] ====== start
W/webview(7254): Miss a drag as we are waiting for WebCore's response for touch down.
D/webview(7254): [TouchEvent::Down] [true][false] [62,-5]
W/webview(7254): Miss a drag as we are waiting for WebCore's response for touch down.
```

This is in my device of version 2.2.1 for **ONLY SWIPE**

```
 W/webview(626): Miss a drag as we are waiting for WebCore's response for touch down.
 W/webview(626): Miss a drag as we are waiting for WebCore's response for touch down.
 W/webview(626): Miss a drag as we are waiting for WebCore's response for touch down.
```

Now My doubt is it a Problem with **cordova version** or **my implementation** or **device**

Comment: Cordova 2.1.0? You should upgrade to 2.7.0! This might solve some of your compatibility issues.